# Declaring a buffer size within a C++ class: BUFFER_SIZE is not a type

Tags: c++, class, vector

Sorry in advance for the inundation of code below. First time posting so I want to be thorough.

I'm experimenting with an existing, functioning XML parser written in C++ by moving variables and methods from main to a class called XMLParser. My goal is to clean up the code a little bit to make future maintenance a little easier.

After moving variables and methods over, I'm getting the following error specifically after moving my buffer declaration from `main` to `XMLParser.hpp`":

```
/[build directory]/XMLParser.hpp:37:30: error: ‘BUFFER_SIZE’ is not a type
     std::vector<char> buffer(BUFFER_SIZE);
```

`buffer` is a std::vector container whose size is declared by `const int BUFFER_SIZE`. `BUFFER_SIZE` is declared and initialized in `refillBuffer.hpp`. The parser runs without issues when `buffer` is declared in `main` but not `XMLParser.hpp`. What's the difference between accessing `BUFFER_SIZE` in `refillBuffer` from `main` and from `XMLParser.hpp` that's causing the program to bug out like this? Is there a scope issue in `XMLParser.hpp` that's preventing it from seeing `BUFFER_SIZE`?

main.cpp:

```
#include "refillBuffer.hpp"
#include "XMLParser.hpp"

int main() {
    XMLParser parser;

    // std::vector<char> buffer(BUFFER_SIZE);
    // auto pc = buffer.cend();

    while (true) {
        // parse XML using methods and variables in parser
    }
    // print report here
    return 0;
}
```

XMLParser.hpp

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_XMLPARSER_HPP
#define INCLUDE_XMLPARSER_HPP

#include "refillBuffer.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class XMLParser {
public:
    int textsize = 0;
    int loc = 0;
    int expr_count = 0;
    int function_count = 0;
    int class_count = 0;
    int file_count = 0;
    int decl_count = 0;
    int comment_count = 0;
    int return_count = 0;
    int literal_string_count = 0;
    int block_comment_count = 0;
    int depth = 0;
    long total = 0;
    bool intag = false;
    std::vector<char> buffer(BUFFER_SIZE);
    auto pc = buffer.cend();

    // methods using above variables go here
};
#endif
```

refillBuffer.hpp

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_REFILLBUFFER_HPP
#define INCLUDE_REFILLBUFFER_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 4096;

// Refill the buffer preserving the unused data
std::vector<char>::const_iterator refillBuffer(std::vector<char>::const_iterator pc, std::vector<char>& buffer, long& total);

#endif
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

To do an in-class initialization, it needs to be a "brace or equals initializer" (see [[class.mem]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#10.sentence-3)). That is,

```cpp
struct S {
  int a = 5;       // OK
  int b{ 10 };     // OK
  int c = { 20 };  // OK

  int d(1);        // Not OK
};
```

In particular, the error message you get is because the compiler thinks that for something of the form `int e(X)`, you're declaring a function `e` taking an `X` and returning an `int`, since that's not a valid default member initializer. However, for your problem `BUFFER_SIZE` is not a type.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The way I declare buffer above is the equivalent of writing the header for a member function instead of declaring a vector of size `BUFFER_SIZE`.

The solution was to declare the `buffer` and `pc` vectors like this:

```
std::vector<char> buffer = std::vector<char>(BUFFER_SIZE);
std::vector<char>::const_iterator pc = buffer.cend();
```